# Rails: Is this a use case for Single Table Inheritance (STI)?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, database-normalization, sti

Consider this setup.  Please understand that our setup is much more detailed but this is a simple example.

`competition` which has `name`.  This is an annual competition.
`competition_instances` which has `location`, `starts_at`.
Each competition has `sports` which has `name`.

Example:
`competition`.`name`: "Super Bowl" has different `competition_instances` every year but `sport` remains the same.
Conversely, `competition`.`name`: "Olympics" has different `competition_instances` and different `sports` in each `competition_instance`.

Would it be best to create `competition_sports` and `competition_instance_sports` with `competition_instance_sports` as a subclass of `competition_sports`?

**GOAL**:  Use `competition_instance_sports` records if they exist, otherwise use the `competition_sports` record.  In our real world app, each competition/competition_instance can have 20-50 sport records.  How can we best achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just thinking of the case where there are standard sports which are always in the Olympics and some which are added on, such as those proposed by the host country.

I would use [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), in a ["reverse manner"](https://gist.github.com/runemadsen/1242485).

```
class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competition_instances
  has_many :competition_sports, as: :event
end

class CompetitionInstance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :competition
  has_many :competition_sports, as: :event

  def events_array  # neater by sacrificing ActiveRecord methods
    competition.competition_sports + competition_sports
  end

  def events        # messier, returns ActiveRecord relationship
    CompetitionSport.where( " ( event_id = ? AND event_type = 'Competition' ) OR
                              ( event_id = ? AND event_type = 'CompetitionInstance')", competition_id, id )
  end
end

class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, as: :competition_sport
end

class CompetitionSport < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sport
  belongs_to :event, polymorphic: true
end
```

This allows:

```
competition.competition_sports            # standard sports
competition_instance.competition_sports   # only those specific for this instance
competition_instance.events               # includes sports from both
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I understand from the question I cannot see where STI will be helpful in this situation. However a join table will get you where you want.

I suggest creating a new table `sports`, this model will have all the specific details of each sport. The `competition_instance.rb` will have one/many `sport.rb`. `competiton.rb` will have many `sports` through `competition_instance.rb`.

**competition.rb**

```
Class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :competition_instances
   has_many :sports, through: :competition_instances
end
```

**competition_instance.rb**

```
Class CompetitionInstance < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :competition
   belongs_to :sport
end
```

**sport.rb**

```
Class Sport < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :competition_instances
end
```

By using this design you will be able to achieve the following:

1- You will have your predefined sports in your database along with their specific properties.

2- Each competition will have `.sports` which will give all the sports in this competition for the olympics case.

3- You will be able to set specific properties for each competition instance (example `event_start_time` and `event_end_time`) in the competition instance table.

Answer (score 1):

Aiming at the original question of "Is this a use case for STI", it will be difficult to say if this is or not without seeing the full complexity of your environment. But here's are some things to consider:

Abridged from [How (and When) to Use Single Table Inheritance in Rails - eugenius blog](http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/):

> STI should be **considered** when dealing with model classes that **share much of the same *functionality and data fields***, but you want more granular control over extending or adding to each class individually. Rather than duplicate code or forego the individual functionalities, STI permits you to use keep your data in a single table while writing specialized functionality.

You've simplified your example, but it sounds like `competition` and `competition_instance` are NOT essentially the same object, with minor behavioral differences. With what you've described, I would probably rename these objects to `event` and `competition`, or whatever makes better sense to you in terms of illustrating what these objects are actually representing. I think of 'The Olympics' as a generic event, and '100m Dash' as a competition taking place at The Olympics. Or "The SuperBowl" only hosted one competition in 2014, "SuperBowl XLIX".

You've also tagged this question with `database-normalization`, which STI won't help. If the attributes differ slightly between your shared objects you'll end up with null fields everywhere.

I refer you to the other answers here to see how you should probably set those objects up to behave as desired.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a case for single table inheritance, because `competition_instance` is not a substitute for `competition` and 1 `competition` can have many `competition_instances`. So you have 3 tables:

```
competitions
sports
competition_instances
```

`competition_instances` has a foreign key to `competitions` because 1 `competition` can have many `competition_instances` but each `competition_instance` has exactly one `competition`.

Whether you attach `sports` to `competitions` or `competition_instances` depends on the specific constraints of your use case. I don't exactly know what you mean by "each `competition/competition_instance` can have 20-50 `sport` records". I would expect each `competition_instance` to have exactly one `sport`, so you might leave it at that, or you might attach a collection of `sports` to a `competition` as well, so that you can retrieve new `competitions` by `sport` before there is a `competition_instance`. I'd need more details on your use case to give you further advice.